# Проблема в работе с Discord

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, discord

Когда в дискорде отправляешь обычное сообщение, то в HTML коде оно не разбивается. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но если сообщение будет содержать HTML тег, то в коде оно разобьется как показано на фото.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как отправлять сообщения содержащие HTML теги, чтобы Discord их не разбивал.

Comment: А разве есть какой-то другой способ отобразить цельный тег html в виде текста, так, чтобы он не читался как тег?